# Keep cmd.exe console window with specific title open?

Tags: windows, batch-file

in Windows 7 x64 SP1 I need to create a batch file (.bat) which keeps the cmd.exe console window open and has a specific title:

```
@ECHO OFF
title notepadtest
@ECHO ON
start "" /WAIT notepad
```

But this batch file keeps opening an infinite number of cmd.exe console windows in an unstoppable loop!

How can I create a batch file (.bat) which creates only ONE cmd.exe console window and keeps it open and has a specific title?

Comment: It's working fine on windows 10 machine, Have you tried on other windows version?

Comment: what is the name of your batchfile..? the actual name of it. `notepad.bat` perhaps?

Comment: Yes, the name of the batch file is notepad.bat. Is there something wrong with that?

Comment: Did you see the answer below explaining the problem with that?

Comment: You can also use `PAUSE` right after the `start` command without the option `/w`.

Comment: @SvenKrüger how does that resolve the error of opening the script over and over?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard ...Should have read not only the title... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please ensure that your batchfile is not named `notepad.cmd` or `notepad.bat` or anything like any system or external command. Name it something like `mynotepad.cmd` instead., then try this one please:

```
@echo off
title notepadtest
start "" /w notepad.exe
```

cmdline and batch files typically works like this. When a command is issued, it first checks the local path, where the script was launched from for the command, if not found, it will check your environment and system environment. So if you name a batchfile `notepad.bat` your batch is actually starting itself over and over, instead of finding `notepad.exe` in the environment variables.

Always name batch files something unique and not system/external command related.

Always use full executable name in a batch, like `start "" /w notepad.exe` and not `start "" /w notepad`

Comment: Thank you very much! Naming the batch file as "notepad.bat" was the cause of the infinite loop error. Now I know that the name of a batch file is important. But what is the difference between "/WAIT" and "/w"?

Comment: `/wait` is the "official" switch (mentioned in the help) and therefore should be preferred (also for readability). `/w` is just the short form for us lazy typers.

Comment: @user1580348 There is not difference between `/w` and `/wait` I only typed the short `/w` as it is shorter. I actually created that to show to rather use `notepad.exe` and not just notepad.

Comment: @Stephan You said it, not me :)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard `I only typed the short /w as it is shorter` is just another way to say "I'm lazy too" `:P`

Comment: To remove the current working directory from the search that's used by `CreateProcess` and CMD, define the environment variable `NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath` with any value, such as "1". You can manually add "." to the end of `PATH` to search the working directory last.

Comment: @eryksun, You are correct and in practice it's usually the case, but theoretically it can not be relied upon, unless you also rebuild the path list. the current directory alias can already be present in the the beginning of the path list.

Comment: @sst, sorry, I meant only when configuring the system. I wouldn't set `NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath` in a script. It's a policy to be set by the system owner or administrator. Adding "." back to the end of `PATH` is another decision for an administrator, but without it, some (badly written) programs are likely to break.